# How to fetch attachments in a task using Asana API?

Tags: api, task, attachment, asana

I found no API to fetch these values. Please tell how can I?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Asana)

The API does not currently provide access to attachments. We've heard other requests for this so it is something we are considering adding in the future, but I can't provide any specifics on the timeline.

Comment: I hope to see this feature implemented soon! ;)